# Image segmentation evaluation - single class problem

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, data-science, image-segmentation

What is the best method to evaluate the quality of a segmentation algorithm when the majority of the image has multiple objects all belonging to the same class.

For example: 
If I had an algorithm that segments books in this image of a bookcase - with a single bounding box per book.
[Bookcase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZ030.png)

I have had a look at various blog posts on segmentation evaluation and the majority seem to showcase examples of multiclass problems where it is fairly obvious if a prediction is not accurate - the bounding boxes do/do-not overlap for that class.

My first thoughts are that a tradition IoU or thematic accuracy would not work on this kind of problem because an output containing a single 'book' polygon (completely under-segmenting) that covers the entire image would still return high scoring metrics as almost all of the image is in fact 'book', however it is in fact very poorly segmenting the image.

I'm not sure if I have framed my problem well, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO, which is about *specific coding* questions; your question is way too broad, please do take some time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @desertnaut Thank you for your feedback, I have read through these guides and am not quite sure the best way to make my question more specific beyond uploading my ground truth and an example prediction. I am just after a segmentation evaluation metric that would tackle this kind of problem.

Comment: You are welcome - just keep in mind that not all questions are suitable for SO

Answer (score 0):

I would try to tackle this problem using these solutions:

1. **Compute the Dice/IoU coefficients of the background class**

   - this is a simple solution for the semantic segmentation results
   - if the algorithm would get good results in both foreground and background metrics you can at least generally tell it performs well
2. **Computing the average of metrics for instance segmented separated objects**

   - Your problem seems like an instance segmentation to me
   - Calculating the metrics for each distinct object is then easy - you can compute dice/jaccard coefficients for every object separately and than average the results of all instances as in [this great article with more information about segmentation metrics.](https://www.jeremyjordan.me/evaluating-image-segmentation-models/)